# Best way to forward/redirect methods/attributes in python class without redundant code/docstrings?

Tags: python, class, oop, forwarding

I have a project, with some modules each of which contains a class doing their respective thing. Then I have an API class for the user. The API class instantiate those classes, and should forward/redirect to those who are doing the actual processing. I have the following questions:

1. How do I do the forwarding without rewriting what seems to me redundant code? For example, say `Foo` is the API class, `Bar` is a module class, then now I am writing something like:

   ```
   class Foo:
       def __init__(self, bar: Bar):
           self.bar = bar
       def name(self):
           return self.bar.name()
   ```

   I explicitly wrote `name` method in `Foo`, which just returns `name()` of `Bar`. Isn't this redundant? Is there an "automatic" way to forward the call?
2. In the `bar` class I'd write some docstrings. Is there a way to "port" these docstrings to the API class `Foo`? Writing them again in `Foo` would be redundant and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try redirecting the `__getattr__` magic method:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: Bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.bar, attr)
```

This would redirect all functions to the `bar` variable.

For multiple classes:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: Bar, foo: Foo, blah: Blah):
        self.bar = bar
        self.foo = foo
        self.blah = blah
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self.bar, attr):
            return getattr(self.bar, attr)
        elif hasattr(self.foo, attr):
            return getattr(self.foo, attr)
        else:
            return getattr(self.blah, attr)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this the "standard" way, or is this a hack? Asking as I am still new to python (or coding). Better yet, is what I described that having a "API class and other classes to handle respective processing" a "standard" way?

Comment: @Alex This isn't a hack IMO, since it's only modifying magic methods, but that is normal :)

Comment: @Alex I say this is the *only* viable way tbh

Comment: Did you try the docstring code?

Comment: @blhsing Yeah. I did

Comment: `__doc__` is supposed to be a string attribute, not a method.

Comment: @blhsing Sorry edited mine. I pasted the wrong code, in my IDE I had the parenthesis.

Comment: @U12-Forward Thanks!

Comment: @blhsing sorry what do you mean "the docstring code"?

Comment: That's even more incorrect. `__doc__` is not a method to begin with.

Comment: @blhsing So `inspect.getdoc`?

Comment: @blhsing What should I use?

Comment: If I had multiple module class, and I would like to "port" all of their methods/attributs to the API, what do I do then?

Comment: @Alex This code should do, depends on what you mean exactly

Comment: @U12-Forward Like I already pointed out, `__doc__` is supposed to be a string attribute bound to a class. The OP wants the docstring of the class of the `bar` object to be applied to the class of `Foo`, and you simply cannot obtain `bar` at the class level. What I do in my answer is the only way I can think of.

Comment: @blhsing So I removed that part...

Comment: @U12-Forward I meant if `Foo` takes more than one classes, for example, `Bar` and `Abc`. I would like to "port" the methods of both `Bar` and `Abc` to `Foo`.

Comment: @Alex Edited my answer

Comment: @Alex Feel free to mark it if my answer may've helped.

Comment: @U12-Forward thank you!

Comment: @U12-Forward Still trying to understand the approaches - I assume you must know about blhsing's approach in the other answer, right? i.e. just assigning the methods.  What's the advantage/disadvantage of `__getattr__` and that approach?

Comment: @Alex I say his approach is a bit more of a "hack", his assigning the name attribute as a variable representing a function, but mine is just a standard way of "redirecting" attributes,

Answer (score 3):

You can assign `bar.name` to `self.name`. Same goes for the docstring with the `__doc__` attribute of the class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: Bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.name = bar.name
        self.__class__.__doc__ = bar.__class__.__doc__
```

Comment: the method `bar.name` takes a `self` as the first arg; here what would `self` points to in `Foo.name`?

Comment: The object that a method is bound to is automatically passed as the `self` argument, so `bar` would be passed as `self` when `bar.name` is called.

Comment: here is the docstring of `Bar.name()` automatically ported to `Foo.name`? Is your approach more standard/correct than the `__getattr__` in @U12-Forward answer?

Comment: Still trying to understand different approaches. Compared to using `__getattr__` what is the advantage/disadvantage of this approach? I searched around a bit, and obviously, you know about `__getattr__`, but didn't recommend it.